# send selected values from JavaScript to Controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

this is my view from which i want to send the data. when i select class name i want to send it to **Controller** by **Ajax**

```
<select class="form-control" name="persent_class" id="class">
<?php foreach ($all_classes as $class) : ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $class['class_name']?>"><?php echo 
  $class['class_name']?></option>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
```

this is my **ajax** function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#class").change(function () {
            var c = $("#class").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?=base_url()?>index.php/Welcome/get_class_name",
                data: {"c":c},
                dataType:"json",
                cache: "false",

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is my **controller function**:

```
public function get_class_name()
        {
            $id=$this->input->post('c');
            echo json_encode($id);

        }
```

Comment: ok, and what's your problem/question?

Comment: @delboy1978uk i want to send the data to controller by ajax.

Comment: you already do that.... use google developer console and take a look @network tab

Comment: @sintakonte i can't send the value. console show this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at admission:734

Comment: yes i include jquery.js

Comment: maybe (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/), if thats the case you should replace any `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: it does't work @AnandPandey

Comment: Are you using vue.js

Comment: no im using jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this script, some line changed and you forget echo base_url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#class").change(function () {
            var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
            var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/Welcome/get_class_name",
                data: {"c":valueSelected},
                dataType:"json",
                cache: "false",

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Which line was changed? And why?